# Akka Kafka consumer in Java

Tags: akka

I am new to Akka programming language and would like to know if someone had already developed Akka based Kafka consumer in Java language. Can you please guide and assist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [Reactive Kafka](https://github.com/softwaremill/reactive-kafka), an [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/java.html?_ga=1.205056018.300933472.1420934795) powered implementation that allows you to pull data from Kafka using streaming. These libraries do provide an Java API.

Comment: There's examples in the link I pointed out :-) https://github.com/softwaremill/reactive-kafka